# How to handle a future option inside of a playframework controller?

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I currently have the following signature for my method call:

```
val article:Future[Option[Article]] = articleService.getById(1)
```

My controller looks like:

```
def show(id: Int) = Action.async { request =>
  articleService.getById(id).onSuccess {
    case articleOpt => {
      articleOpt.map{ 
         article => Ok("....")
      }
    }
  }
   Ok("fail")      
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of handling a `Future[Option[Model]]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def show(id: Int) = Action.async { request =>
  articleService.getById(id).map {
    case Some(article) => Ok(article) 
    case None => Ok("...")
  }.recover{case ex => Ok("fail")}
}
```

Even more cleaner way requires using smth like scalaz's `ReaderT`

Comment: This is right, but it's probably even better to use `InternalServerError("fail")` and `NotFound("...")`.

Comment: @danielnixon will 'case ex' catch everything?  so would I log the exception here in play or globally?

Comment: maybe, not familiar with play, just suggested basing on TS example. But obviously this question has nothing common with only play specific topics

Comment: @Blankman you will catch excaptions from future of getById method, or, perhaps that appeard during construction of some of Ok's

Answer (score 1):

You can also use scalaz monad transformer OptionT:

```
import scalaz.OptionT

def show(id: Int) = Action.async { 
    OptionT(articleService.getById(id))
       .map(a => Ok(s"found: ${a.name}"))
       .getOrElse(NotFound("Not found"))
}
```

Comment: Same thing with `import cats.data.OptionT`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
 def show(id: Int) = Action.async { request =>
  articleService.getById(id) map { op =>
        op match {
            case Some(acle) => Ok(s"found: ${acle.name}")
            case None => NotFound("Not found")                  
        }}
}
```

Comment: onComplete returns Unit: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future@onComplete[U](f:scala.util.Try[T]=>U)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit